# link two j spinners where number range of one depends on value selected in the other

Tags: java, spinner

I'm  new to Java and trying to understand if the following is possible:

I have a number spinner ranging from 30 to 55, call it spinner1. I want to link a second spinner, spinner2, where the range of values depends on the number chosen in spinner1. e.g. if the user chooses 30 in spinner1 they can choose a number between 1 and 100 in spinner2. Selecting 55 in spinner1 limits the range of values in spinner2 to between 1 and 50.

I have read the JSpinner cycling tutorial and understand how two spinners can be linked but there both spinners have fixed limits. I really jsut want o know if this is possible and any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Well from what I read, if you really just want to know if this is possible, the answer is : yes. You're welcome.

Comment: Seriously though, I think you just need to check how to use SpinnerModels. You can begin by taking a look at the doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerModel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You link the Spinner models rather than the spinners themselves.

```
SpinnerNumberModel model1 = new SpinnerNumberModel( 10, 10, 90, 10 );
model1.addChangeListener( this );
SpinnerNumberModel model2 = new SpinnerNumberModel( 10, 10, 19, 1 );
```

The idea is to let spinner 1 step from 10 to 90 by 10 and force spinner 2 into the interval
`[spinner1.getValue(), spinner1.getValue()+9]` This is done by the ChangeListener method

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
  SpinnerNumberModel model = (SpinnerNumberModel)e.getSource();
  Integer value = (Integer)model.getValue();
  model2.setMinimum( value );
  model2.setMaximum( value + 9 );
  if( (Integer)model2.getValue() < value ){
    model2.setValue( value );
  } else if( (Integer)model2.getValue() > value + 9 ){
    model2.setValue( value + 9 );
  }
}
```

The models are passed to the JSpinner constructor:

```
JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner( model1 );
JSpinner spinner2 = new JSpinner( model2 );
```